# PHP file size checks the first image only

Tags: php

I'm trying to upload a main image from the first input and multiple images from the second input. The problem is that my second input checks the first selected image only. For example, my limit is 2MB. If I select a 1Mb image then a 3Mb, then it uploads both without any errors and I don't understand why. It should display "max 2MB". If I select the 3Mb image first, then the smaller one, it displays the error message. That's why I think that it checks the first one only. This is the problematic part:

```
if ($_FILES["images"]["size"][$i] > $maxSize || $_FILES["mainimage"]["size"] > $maxSize) {
    $errorMsg = "max 2MB";
}
```

I think I use the [$i] correctly here, so I have no idea what's wrong.

Here's my full code:

```
    if ($ok = 1) {
        //IMAGE UPLOAD
        $filesTempName = $_FILES['images']['tmp_name'];
        $mainImageTempName = $_FILES['mainimage']['tmp_name'];
        $counted = count($filesTempName);
        $allowed_types = array(IMAGETYPE_PNG, IMAGETYPE_JPEG, IMAGETYPE_GIF);
        if (!empty($mainImageTempName)){
            $mainImageDetectedType = exif_imagetype($mainImageTempName);
        }
        
        if ($counted > 5) {
            $errorMsg = "Maximum 5 képet lehet feltölteni!";
        } else {
            for ($i = 0; $i < $counted; $i++) {
                if (empty($filesTempName[$i]) && empty($mainImageTempName)) {
                    $mainimage = "";
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $stmt->close();
                    $link->close();
                } elseif (!empty($mainImageTempName) && empty($filesTempName[$i])) {
                    $mainImageDetectedType = exif_imagetype($mainImageTempName);
                    if ($_FILES["mainimage"]["size"] > $maxSize) {
                        $errorMsg = "Minden képnek 2 Mb-nál kisebbnek kell lennie!";
                    } elseif (!in_array($mainImageDetectedType, $allowed_types)) {
                        $errorMsg = "A képek csak PNG/JPG/JPEG/GIF formátumban elfogadottak!";
                    } else {
                        $mainImageFile = $mainImageTempName;
                        if (is_uploaded_file($mainImageFile) && !empty($mainImageFile)) {
                            $mainimage = "uploads/" . time() . $_FILES["mainimage"]["name"];
                            move_uploaded_file($mainImageFile, $mainimage);
                            $stmt->execute();
                            $stmt->close();
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    $detectedType = exif_imagetype($filesTempName[$i]);
                    if ($_FILES["images"]["size"][$i] > $maxSize || $_FILES["mainimage"]["size"] > $maxSize) {
                        $errorMsg = "Minden képnek 2 Mb-nál kisebbnek kell lennie!";
                    } elseif (!in_array($detectedType, $allowed_types) || !in_array($mainImageDetectedType, $allowed_types)) {
                        $errorMsg = "A képek csak PNG/JPG/JPEG/GIF formátumban elfogadottak!";
                    } else {
                        $mainImageFile = $mainImageTempName;
                        if (is_uploaded_file($mainImageFile) && !empty($mainImageFile)) {
                            $mainimage = "uploads/" . time() . $_FILES["mainimage"]["name"];
                            move_uploaded_file($mainImageFile, $mainimage);
                        }

                        $stmt->execute();
                        $stmt->close();

                        $productid = $link->insert_id;
                        $statement = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO images(thumbnailimage, productid) VALUES(?, ?)");

                        for ($i = 0; $i < $counted; $i++) {
                            $file = $filesTempName[$i];
                            if (is_uploaded_file($file) && !empty($file)) {
                                $data = "uploads/" . time() . $_FILES["images"]["name"][$i];
                                move_uploaded_file($file, $data);
                                $statement->bind_param("si", $data, $productid);
                                $statement->execute();
                            }
                        }

                        $statement->close();
                        $link->close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: did to try upload one by one? or else you can check the image size by a loop before the upload happens and display error

Comment: Yes, I tried. If I select the big size image only, it displays the error correctly. I'm checking the image size by a loop already, what do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this loop:

```
if ($_FILES["images"]["size"][$i] > $maxSize || $_FILES["mainimage"]["size"] > $maxSize) {
                        $errorMsg = "Minden képnek 2 Mb-nál kisebbnek kell lennie!";
                    } elseif (!in_array($detectedType, $allowed_types) || !in_array($mainImageDetectedType, $allowed_types)) {
                        $errorMsg = "A képek csak PNG/JPG/JPEG/GIF formátumban elfogadottak!";
                    } else {  
// .... other commands

}
```

The system will check whether the size of an uploaded file is larger than the $maxSize, but the next iteration will overwrite the previous one because you are storing the result in a single variable $errorMsg. Hence if the last uploaded file and the "first main file" is not larger than the $maxSize, the system will return the other result.

Hence, the normal practice , is to increment the error count in each iteration when the conditions meet your pre-defined checking.

A slightly revised codes to fix the problem can be like this:

```
$filesize_error=0;
if ($_FILES["images"]["size"][$i] > $maxSize || $_FILES["mainimage"]["size"] > $maxSize) {

                       // $errorMsg = "Minden képnek 2 Mb-nál kisebbnek kell lennie!";
$filesize_error++;

                    } elseif (!in_array($detectedType, $allowed_types) || !in_array($mainImageDetectedType, $allowed_types)) {
                        $errorMsg = "A képek csak PNG/JPG/JPEG/GIF formátumban elfogadottak!";
                    } else {  
// .... other commands

}
```

You can then check whether $filesize_error is larger than 0 (after the iterations) to determine whether one or more files you uploaded has exceeded the maximum file size allowed, and do what you want.